# How manage operations in servlet using RequestDispatcher

Tags: java, servlets

i would like to ask if there is any better solution to manage operation in servlet in my case which is:

i have many operation(it takes around 10s) to parse data and present them to user. I would like to show user some interface and some display animation, and when data will be ready show it to the user at same jsp. I got servlet which is maped for example to /new and then i would like to show new.jsp

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("new.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

and than make this long operation, but when i do it like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    
      request.getRequestDispatcher("new.jsp").forward(request, response);
      /*
      here are my operations
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
       */
```

Im getting

```
      Cannot forward after response has been committed
```

it shows new.jsp and i see at tomcat operations are succesfull but my data isnt passed through jsp

```
       $.get("NewSearchController", function(responseJson) {
```

it works if i make in this servlet just redirection to new.jsp and then take all this data using another servlet but is it good practice? How should i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it works if i make in this servlet just redirection to new.jsp and then take all this data using another servlet but is it good practice? How should i do it?

Most traditional web application do the same thing when trying to display some message to let user wait. I think this is good enough.

You can also fire AJAX call and block the user interaction, you can use promise to achieve this.

```
//before the ajax call
$.blockUI();//or a bootstrap modal will do
$.get("/NewSearchController").then(function(response){
     //handle your response
     $.unblockUI();
}).fail(function(err){
     //handle error
     $.unblockUI();
});
```

However, I will highly recommend you to migrate to JAX-RS if you are dealing with RESTful service a lot.

EDIT:
Seems like you want to achieve something like:
 1. Display some sort of layout before the data is complete loading.
 2. Update the pages when the operation is done.

For this, you could just make your new.jsp doing nothing than a layout.

new.jsp

```
<!--omit html layout-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get("yourapi").then(function(data){
            //handle your data, updating the #main div sound logical
        }).fail(function(err){
           //display an error message maybe?
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="data">
</div>
```

This way, you could display at least the page layout while user is waiting and knowing the application is not just freeze.

Do let me know if this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: I think its not what i would expected. The main goal here is to hide new.jsp so i use /new what;s mapped to NewSearchController (servlet). And now i want to load new.jsp file 1/2 and when all data will be ready fill the rest of new.jsp. Your answer looks like i loaded new.jsp and then i want get my NewSearchController (servlet). And its great and do all i want, but how can i load new.jsp using /new and i dont want create new servet just for redirection. Is it possible?

Comment: It is exactly what i want achiev but... :D i dont want call www.example.com/new.jsp, i want call ww.example.com/new, and i would like to handle this in 1 servlet. Do You know what i mean?

Comment: You can't really do that, servlet spawn 1 thread per request,. Displaying a page and loading data has to be in two request if you want it to happen in two different time

Comment: Okay than. Thx bro!